# XMLHttpRequest.open does not work with IE9 (though XMLHttpRequest object is supported)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest, internet-explorer-9, w3c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SCRIPT5: Access is denied in IE9 on xmlhttprequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5793831/script5-access-is-denied-in-ie9-on-xmlhttprequest)

Consider the following HTML code :-

```
<!-- Check for XMLHttpRequest object in IE 9 -->
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        alert("XMLHttpRequest supported by browser");
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.open("GET", "books.xml", false);    <!-- Line 1 -->
        alert("reching??");
        xhttp.send();

    }
    if(window.ActiveXObject){
        alert("ActiveXObject supported by browser");
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

As per [W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp), IE7+ supports XMLHttpRequest object. I am using the same for IE9.

Yes, the object is supported by IE9 as a get the alert for the same.
However, XMLHttpRequest's method open is not working. Browser stops at the line 1 shown in the above code.

Why is it so??

I also searched a [Microsoft's link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535874%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Two different ways of creating XML HTTP Request Object is shown :

1. xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest;
2. xhttp = getXMLHttpRequest();

1st way gives the same problem at open method. 2nd way returns a null object.
In the same link, I also found that many people are facing the same problem with open method of XMLHttpRequest object in IE but I guess no solution is written there too. :(

Comment: That page seems to work on me using IE9 as I get all three alert messages.  Are there any messages in the console in the developer tools?  (F12 -> Console)

Comment: @DonCruickshank Yes. When I debugged the script, it stops at Line 1. The Console Message is "SCRIPT5: Access is denied."

Comment: Moreover, if I call the open method from try-catch block, I can alert the Exception caught. So I guess there is some exception thrown here.

Comment: Are you running this page via the `file` or `http` protocol?

Comment: @DonCruickshank: Via File. This is an HTML File in my local machine. And the "books.xml" file is also in the same folder.