# SCRIPT5 : Access denied error on ie with XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, internet-explorer-9

I've got a SCRIPT5 error with an XMLHttpRequest and I can't fix the problem even with this question : [SCRIPT5: Access is denied in IE9 on xmlhttprequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5793831/script5-access-is-denied-in-ie9-on-xmlhttprequest)

Here's my code :

```
function getXDomainRequest()
{
        var xdr = null;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xdr=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
    xdr=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
        return xdr;        
}

function sendData()
{
        var xdr = getXDomainRequest();
        xdr.onload = function() 
        {
                var xml = xdr.responseXML; 
                var prod = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("produit");          
        }
        xdr.open("GET", "http://www.mysite.tm.fr/page.php?var1="+ var1 +"");
        xdr.send();
}
```

Any help will be very very very appreciated!

Precision : The distant website returns me an XML content like this :

```
<liste>
<produits>
<produit>...</produit>
<produit>...</produit>
<produit>...</produit>
</produits>
</liste>
```

Comment: Is the website sending proper CORS headers?

Comment: What do you mean by proper CORS headers? Should I add something special to the distant website? FYI in Firefox and Chrome its working perfeclty

Comment: have you set  Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to your server side.?

Answer (score 2):

IE9 doesn't support CORS for XHR. IE10 will. [Source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/02/09/cors-for-xhr-in-ie10.aspx).

However, IE8/9 supports CORS with [XDomainRequest](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx).

Comment: even ie8 supports cors though, with `XDomainRequest`

Comment: Yeah, which is why the answer says "for XHR" :-)

Comment: Well it should say to replace XHR with XdomainRequest then :) :) :)