# SCRIPT5: Access is denied. on ie9

Tags: jquery

my website just can't visit using ie. And the problem that appear in ie developer tools says that "

```
SCRIPT5: Access is denied.

jquery-1.8.3.min.js, line 2 character 69317
```

and i have tried this link [SCRIPT5: Access Denied on IE9 due to jQuery.min CDN file in Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12232475/script5-access-denied-on-ie9-due-to-jquery-min-cdn-file-in-wordpress)

and tried using "development version" of JQuery but not success. 
and again also tried to use jquery version 1.8.1 full and mini version again not success.

any suggestion please?

Comment: Where within the html page are you including your scripts?

Comment: i put that in head section of an HTML page as follow

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <script src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: you need to figure out what line of your code is causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
this is because somewhere on my page I got another JavaScript registered and that js file is getting me problem.

sorry to bother to you all.

Comment: I'm getting this exact issue but when you say Javascript do you mean you were loading in another version of jquery so there were two versions of jquery? or did you mean other scripts that were reliant on jquery?