# JQuery.load() page containingJavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html page which contains the some javascript to generate a chart from Google API. WHen I access the page directly, it works as expected, showing the chart.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load('visualization', '1.0', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
   //// code to generate chart
   var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
   chart.draw(data, options);
}
</script>
<div id="chart_div">
   Chart Div
</div>
```

I want to load this chart into a  on another page. I tried using JQuery's $.get and $.load, but neither are working. IF I add some text to the page and call get/load i can see the text but not the chart - it seems the Javascript is not executing.

I added `alert('msg')` and saw that the `google.load` got called, but no other JS was being called.

From the other page where I want include the chart I have the following JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#test').load('chart?param=1', function () {
        alert('Load was performed.');
    });
});
```

but the 'load was performed' never gets hit.

Comment: What errors do you get in your console?

Comment: There are syntax errors in the code you have provided. A `}` for no reason in the first part and no `});` to close document ready.

Comment: Sorry misssed the brackets when copy / pasting. Looks like an error on google.load('visualization', '1.0', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });

Comment: SCRIPT5009: 'google' is undefined

Comment: ok. So looks like `https://www.google.com/jsapi` is not being loaded.

Comment: I added 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script> to the page I want to load the Div in which eliminates the google.load error, but now I get an error on JQuery SCRIPT5: Access is denied.

Comment: What version of jQuery? This should have been solved in 1.8+

Comment: JQuery 1.8.3. Its within an MVC4 app

Comment: Ok this has evolved into an different question now for which there may already be answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087549/access-denied-to-jquery-script-on-ie http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12232475/script5-access-denied-on-ie9-due-to-jquery-min-cdn-file-in-wordpress

Answer (score 0):

"SCRIPT5009: 'google' is undefined"

I suspect that this `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>` isn't working when you .load() that block of code. Since jQuery is already running try this

```
<!-- get rid of this <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi" -->
<script type="text/javascript">
// does not need $(function()) unless you're running this on its own
// when loading this in using $.load() it's already ready.

$.getScript('https://www.google.com/jsapi', function(){
    google.load('visualization', '1.0', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
});
function drawChart() {
   //// code to generate chart
   var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
   chart.draw(data, options);
}
</script>
```