# Beside from version, operating system and security-level, what can differ two browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, browser

Lets assume I have two almost identical browser setups:

- Both IE9.0 (version 9.0.8112.16421)
- Both with same security-level (Medim-High)
- Both running on WIN7
- The Produce-ID on the two differs and also the language-version (the error throwing being danish, the working being US)

Then, how come that one throws this JavaScript error: `SCRIPT5: Access denied` on jQuery code `form.submit();` where as the other doesn't?

What more than version, operating system and security-level can differ from two browsers?

Can I somewhere change my system or browser settings to provoke this error on my version of IE.

**UPDATE**

I was finally able to reproduce this error myself: When opening my page via a gmail link and try to upload a file - I get `access denied`! (and I have not been drinking).

Comment: Are both running in the same compatibility mode?

Comment: @MartinSmith Yes, both have `Browser Mode: IE9` and `Document Mode: IE7 Standards`

Comment: It sounds like it could be a proxy / firewall issue by the companies IT department that is blocking something like this.

Comment: trusted sites differences ? server-side ip restriction ? anti-malware/spyware security ?

Comment: No, no and maybe. Any suggestion on which anti-malware/spyware security programs could cause JavaScript error: `Access denied` on `form.submit();`

Comment: It might be a cross-domain security setting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5793831/script5-access-is-denied-in-ie9-on-xmlhttprequest

Comment: Might be but I am doing no cross-domain calls